# XP to Windows 7 Upgrade, changing back and forth to AHCI

Tags: windows, installation, ahci

I want to install my Win7 Upgrade Version onto my new Lenovo L440. Before I do that I need my Win XP on there, so my Win7 Key would work.

When trying to install Win XP it gives me a bluescreen, probably due to the fact, that my Samsung 840 EVO SSD runs in AHCI mode.
When trying to change AHCI to IDE in the Bios, it only has the other option of "Compatible".

How do I make it work so I will end up with a legit Win7 Version running with AHCI?
Will "compatible" work for the XP install? Can I change after the XP install to AHCI to install Win7?

(I remember, that I was calling the Microsoft service one time to "activate" my Win7 install. That was probably, because I had installed so often in succession. Could it work here, too?)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a floppy drive (ya right hahahaha) you can put the AHCI driver on it press the F8 key (if I remember correctly) and it will accept the driver from the floppy disk.

For the rest of us who threw there floppy drives out there is **nLite**.  Download and install it, and give it your windows XP CD.  Use it to integrate your AHCI driver and finally make a new ISO.  Burn it to CD and install XP with BIOS in AHCI mode.